# scrapy works in shell, but crawles 0 pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I use scrapy to parse following site: http://www.banki.ru/services/responses/ . When I do step by step parsing through shell everything goes fine, i,e, this line works:

```
response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'banksData')]/text()").re(r'"name":"(.*?)","code"')
```

But when I start to crawl I get following log.

```
2017-06-16 20:59:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: banksru)
2017-06-16 20:59:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'banksru', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'banksru.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['banksru.spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'banki.json'}
2017-06-16 20:59:27 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter']
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (429) <GET http://www.banki.ru/services/responses/> (referer: None)
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <429 http://www.banki.ru/services/responses/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 229,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 119,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/429': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 17, 59, 28, 827696),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/429': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 16, 17, 59, 28, 573054)}
2017-06-16 20:59:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I know that site has robot blocking and problems with user agent, so I change settings.py
Scrapy settings for my project

```
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'banksru'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['banksru.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'banksru.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'www.example.com'

# Obey robots.txt rulesROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'banksru.middlewares.BanksruSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'banksru.middlewares.MyCustomDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    'banksru.pipelines.BanksruPipeline': 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

Code I try to implement is simple:

```
import scrapy

class BankRating(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "banki"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.banki.ru/services/responses/",
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'banksData')]/text()").re(r'"name":"(.*?)","code"')
        rating = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'ratingData')]/text()").re(r'"rating":(.*?),"responseCount"')
        avg_grade = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'ratingData')]/text()").re(r'"middleGrade":(.*?),"middleRating"')
        checked_responses = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(., 'ratingData')]/text()").re(r'"checkedResponseCount":(.*?),"checkedResponseCountForYear"')
        num_responses = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'ratingData')]/text()").re(r'"responseCount":(.*?),"responseCountForYear"')
        solved_problems = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(., 'ratingData')]/text()").re(r'"solvedResponseCount":(.*?),"withAgentAnswer"')
        bank_answers = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'ratingData')]/text()").re(r'"withAgentAnswer":(.*?),"middleGrade"')
        yield name, rating, avg_grade, checked_responses,  num_responses, solved_problems, bank_answers
```

My machine has win8.1 and scrapy is installed for python 3.5. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: It seems you're getting an HTTP code 429, which means sending too much request during a given period of time.

Comment: Try with AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True in settings.py

Comment: @KaushikNP thx. removed # for user_agent, ROBOTSTXT_OBEY , AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED and it went well.

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.

Comment: Removing the hashtag to uncomment line of code to make it work is kind of important lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy as a bot is very **resource intensive** on the server due to it being very **fast** and making **asynchronous calls**, leading to some clear guidelines needed to be followed. Those are so as to make the crawling work in a more tolerable and friendly fashion and not cause any harm to the network.
These are highlighted beautifully in the blog [How to Crawl the Web Politely with Scrapy](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/08/25/how-to-crawl-the-web-politely-with-scrapy/) by Valdir Stumm Jr.

- Web site owners use the [robots.txt file](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)  file to give instructions about their site to web robots; this is called The Robots Exclusion Protocol. This file is usually available at the root of a website and your crawler should follow the rules defined hence
- Websites vary drastically in the number of requests they can handle. [AutoThrottle](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html#throttling-algorithm) automatically adjusts the delays between requests according to the current web server load. It first calculates the latency from one request. Then it will adjust the delay between requests for the same domain in a way that no more than AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY requests will be simultaneously active.

Enabling these in the [settings.py](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=settings.py#settings) should allow for scrapy to crawl through the website. Credits to [@Ding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6805091/ding) for pointing out "HTTP code 429: which means sending too much request during a given period of time"

Answer (score 0):

Sites try to protect themselves responding different statuses when something is wrong with the request.

This particular case is very common but simple. You can bypass it using a common `USER_AGENT`:

**settings.py**

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'
```

Because `scrapy` by default uses something like:

```
"Scrapy/1.3.0 (+http://scrapy.org)"
```